# Magento home page content

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm developing a new **magento 2 theme** to an existing website. However, I have no idea how to **remove the content** inserted on the home page that always appears **above my theme content**.

I have edited the page **"home"** and configured the content to show a specific block of my theme.

Even if I remove the old theme folder, the old content appears.

If this content isn't on page "home", where is it?

The website is **vitaringa.com.br**

Comment: It might be coming from widgets, or from some modules layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **enable the template path hints** to find out which block and template renders the content in the home page. You need to be on Developer Mode at first in order to find the option "Enable Template Path Hints for Store Front" under

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront

To set the developer mode

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

[check here for other different ways to enable the template path hints](https://belvg.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-in-magento-2.html)

Hope with this you can find from where the content on the home page comes from. Obrigardo.

Comment: It says: /home/vitaring/public_html/app/code/Lima/Homepage/view/frontend/templates/main.phtml

Comment: perfect, so its from a custom module Lima_Homepage, either you can make changes in this template file or you can disable this module.

Comment: great, if it's worked, you can accept this as answer. Obrigardo !